# Random Image in Java Dialog Popup Boxes

Tags: java, swing

Random images keep appearing in `all of my` my Java popup boxes: The "inKeep editor" should not be there... the 'inkeep editor' image is a file called 'icon' and is used for the apple dock.

```
String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Home.toolbar, "Please confirm your password to make changes", "Confirm Password", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

[image]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Home.toolbar, "Wrong Password", "Verify Account", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

[image]

I'm setting this image as the dock icon (mac) but not for pop boxes (to my knowledge).

```
Application application = Application.getApplication();
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/icon.png"); // Sets apple icon image
application.setDockIconImage(image);
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of these images in the dialogs? The big red (!) is intended but not the inKeep editor over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior -- a *feature*.  When you give your application an icon, it will display it on top of the default warning/error icons.  This reinforces with the user that the dialog that just popped up is from your application and not another or the OS.

For example, here how it looks using the default Java app icon:

[image]

To add a custom icon, you can do something like this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, icon);
```